# javascript modal dialog aligning to middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, modal-dialog, alignment

```
$("#divDisplayPopUp").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 436,
                width: 939,

            });
```

This code doesnt align the popup into the center of the page.

And its alignment differs in Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Can anyone suggest how to align it to the centre, irrespective of browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this your answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   var maskHeight = $(document).height();
   var maskWidth = $(window).width();

   $('#divDisplayPopUp').css('top', (maskHeight - $('#divDisplayPopUp').height()) / 2);
   $('#divDisplayPopUp').css('left', maskWidth / 2 - $('#divDisplayPopUp').width() / 2);
});
```

I use many times of this and never see any problem.

Comment: where Should I add these lines of code? Is it in Ready Function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      closeText: "Close",
      height: 436,
      width: 939
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[jQuery UI postion.](http://jqueryui.com/position/)**

```
$('#myDialog').dialog('widget').position({
    my:"center", 
    at:"center", 
    of:window
});
```

---

This Postioms your dialog in center with respect to window.

Here is the API Documentation **[.position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)**